# I am getting StackOverflowError while using addonTextChangeListener

Tags: android

I have two EditText editText1 and editText2
Should happen : when user write into editText1 at a time the value entered into editText1 should multiply by 6 and editText2 have that result and vice a versa. 
Happening : When i write into editText1 or editText2 its getting crashed (stackOverFlowError).
For above scenariyo i am using addTextChangeListener.

Comment: can you please post logcat and code ?

Comment: Would you mind showing your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Before iam getting you a working answer.Iam giving you an advice,please go to stackoverflow FAQs and study the basics of this site before posting a question.Because we want to know what you have tried so far before even thinking of answering your question.So please follow the guidelines.**

In this case i have understand,what you are trying to ask for and here is the solution.

And also AAnkit said it becomes a **never ending loop**

```
//First initialize the EditText and addTextChangedListener like shown below.
    editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {@Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {}
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            //Before changing the text inside the EditText you want to remove the text change listener.
                editText1.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            //Here you make the changes to EditText
                editText1.setText("hi");
            //After changing the content of the EditText you want to register the text change listener.
                editText1.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }
        });
```

Hope you got the answer.

Here it is detailed description of this answer.

http://www.revealedtricks4u.com/2015/05/how-to-change-text-of-edittext-inside.html

Iam politely asking you to follow the SO guidelines hereafter.

Comment: If you got your answer.Please mark this as an answer using the Right Tick Button.

Comment: But there is another issue raised: when i am going to set cursor at the end of value by setSelection method it getting indexOutofBoundException when i insert dot. why i am getting this type of error. i doing it like editText1.setSelection(s.length());

Comment: Hey shripal,Yes of course it will be an IndexOutOfBoundsException because you are selecting the index which is larger than the length of the text.So just use editText1.setSelection(s.length()-1);

Comment: You have accepted the answer not mine.Thats ok.Its upto you with your angle of view.Just kidding ha:)

Comment: I applied solution as per you told but not getting cursor at the end.

Comment: you may be setting text to editText1 after the setSelection method.Can u please post the code snippet here as your edit.So i can review it.

Comment: Double currentText = Double.parseDouble(flowRateInput.getText().toString().trim()) * 60.00;
    flowRateInput.removeTextChangedListener(this);
    String strVal = NumberChecker.formatValue(4, currentText);
    flowRateInputForHour.setText(NumberChecker.convertCommaToDot(NumberChecker.roundedDecimal(strVal)));
    flowRateInput.addTextChangedListener(this);
    flowRateInput.setSelection(s.length()-1);

Comment: Ooops you missed a thing and i also forgot to tell.Because the variable s is an Editable instance.So you want to convert to string and get the length like this.flowRateInput.setSelection(s.toString().length(),s.toString().length());.Don't forget to add two parameters as shown above.

Comment: I have did like this but still getting crashed when i am going to insert dot flowRateInputForHour.setSelection(s.toString().length(),s.toString().length());

Comment: Don't have any solution??

Comment: I am not able to insert decimal point

Comment: What so a problem with a Decimal Point

Comment: i have did it...thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are listening **onTextChangeListener** and as per input from user and then you are changing value in another `edittext`, which again calls **onTextChangeListener** and then you are listening it and changing the value of `edit text` again(never ending loop).

Basically you are into never ending loop here :)

Solution:- You have to have a boolean flag, which you should set to true when you change text of `EditText` and in the onTextChangeListener you have to check if this text is changed by code or by user. If by code then do not take action.

Answer (score 0):

Because tour onTextChangeListener is being called continously. EditText1 updates text of edit text2 and edit text updates text of editText1. Thus onTextChangeListener  is being called infinite times.